# Как проверить такой массив объектов ? Vue.js, Vuelidate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

**Задача такова:**
Вернуть `true`, если хотя бы у одного объекта `day_off: false`, и у каждого объекта с `day_off: false` - `work_time.from` и `work_time.to` не должны ровняться `00:00` или `--:--`.

Я использую в проекте **vue.js** с **vuelidate.js**, там можно писать [кастомные](https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-simplest-example) методы валидации, но не хватает знаний, чтобы написать логику. На данный момент готова только:

> Вернуть `true`, если хотя бы у одного объекта `day_off: false`

**Сделал так:**
`const dayValid = (value, vm) => vm.some(el => !el.day_off)`

Буду признателен знатокам или гуру логики JS!

**Сам массив:**

```
schedule: [
  {
    title: "Понедельник",
    work_time: { from: "00:00", to: "00:00" },
    break_time: { from: "00:00", to: "00:00" },
    day_off: false
  },
  {
    title: "Вторник",
    work_time: { from: "00:00", to: "00:00" },
    break_time: { from: "00:00", to: "00:00" },
    day_off: false
  },
  {
    title: "Среда",
    work_time: { from: "00:00", to: "00:00" },
    break_time: { from: "00:00", to: "00:00" },
    day_off: false
  },
  {
    title: "Четверг",
    work_time: { from: "00:00", to: "00:00" },
    break_time: { from: "00:00", to: "00:00" },
    day_off: false
  },
  {
    title: "Пятница",
    work_time: { from: "00:00", to: "00:00" },
    break_time: { from: "00:00", to: "00:00" },
    day_off: false
  },
  {
    title: "Суббота",
    work_time: { from: "00:00", to: "00:00" },
    break_time: { from: "00:00", to: "00:00" },
    day_off: false
  },
  {
    title: "Воскресенье",
    work_time: { from: "00:00", to: "00:00" },
    break_time: { from: "00:00", to: "00:00" },
    day_off: false
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно прогнать массив через цикл:

```
checkOffDay: function (array) {
   for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
      if (!array[i].day_off) {
         return true;
         break;
      }
   }         
},
```

Comment: это и так сделано уже, прочитайте внимательно пожалуйста вопрос :)